# How to let users from certain model view a page while the rest is restricted in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a user model that uses devise for authentication. I also have a userinfo(students) model and an employer model. Both employer and userinfo sign up using the registration model. Then they choose "Continue as employer or student".

1. If they continue as student, they will be asked to fill some info.
   The info each student fills out will be shown to them in their user
   profile page 'userinfo#show". Info of all the students will be
   displayed in the "userinfo#index" page.
2. Then if they continue as employer, they have to fill some different
   info that applies to them. Their info is only displayed in their
   profile page "employer#show".

If I want ONLY EMPLOYERS to see the "userinfo#index" page, how can I do that? That means, if you signed up as a student, you can only see your profile (userinfo#show) and will NOT be able to see "userinfo#index". Employers can see userinfo#index and userinfo#show.

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :userinfo
  has_one :employer

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Userinfo model:

```
class Userinfo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end

def info_complete?
    name? && email? && college? && gpa? && major?
end
```

Employer model:

```
class Employer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end

def info_complete?
    name? && company? && position? && number? && email?
end
```

The migrations I have:

1. devise_create_users.rb
2. create_userinfos.rb
3. add_user_id_to_userinfos.rb
4. create_employers.rb
5. add_user_id_to_employers.rb

Even though it's not shown here, I have a unique function in each model to check if student info has been entered in the userinfo model and if employer info has been entered in the employer model. I have them there because when a user signs up, the program checks if either student information or employer information has been already entered, if so, they don't have to choose "Employer or student". Because they have already chosen. My question is, can I not use those two functions to check if they are an employer or a student? Like, if student info has been filled out, they are a student, so they wont be allowed to see the index page.I just don't know how to implement it.

Comment: Just to be clear, the `Employer` model has information about the user that only gets filled out if the user is an employer? The names make it sound like the `Employer` has information about the user's employer. Also, is it ever possible in your application for a user to have both an `employer` and a `userinfo`?

Comment: @Max Hey Max! Yes, to the first question.Employer model info gets filled out only if that person is an employer. No, it is not possible for a user to have both userinfo AND employer. The way it is setup, as soon as the user signs up, the program checks to see if either userinfo model or employer model is filled out. If neither is filled out, the user gets routed to a page where they have to select if they are an employer or a student(userinfo). Since they can't change after they choose, a user can only have employer OR userinfo.

Comment: Could you use the [authenticate_user!](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers) helper provided by Devise?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma Hey brother! Since Employer and Userinfo model both belong to User, I wouldn't be able to figure out if the user is a student or an employer.

Comment: What about using [`cancancan` and `devise`](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/wiki/Devise---CanCanCan---rolify-Tutorial)?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma That seems like a long fix, I used Rose's solution and it worked. I didn't use any controller code, instead of doing the logic in the controller, I did the logic part in the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'd do it in two parts. First for the model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     ...

     def user_type
         return :user if self.userinfo.present?
         return :employer if self.employer.present?
         return :no_role
     end
end
```

Next for the controller:

```
def index
     if current_user.user_type == :no_role
          redirect_to select_role_path, notice: "Please select your role before continuing"
          return
     elsif current_user.user_type == :user
          redirect_to some_safe_path, notice: "You do not have permission to view this page"
          return
     end

     ... continue with the normal code here
end
```

For a long term solution if you are having different roles consider looking into one of the role management gems like pundit or cancancan. For short term simple projects this solution will work.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a role to your User model could solve this problem. I would suggest using rails' enum feature and adding either a employer/student role, and then writing a helper method in your application controller to check if your current user is an employer/student before displaying the page.

Comment: Hey Riley, please check the last part of my question. I added it recently.